# If cell value same with upper cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to make macro for my daily job, but i cannot use IF as formula due to so many item in my excel file, so solution is to convert formula to VBA code.

I need help to convert if formula to VBA code in excel as below:
=IF(J2<>J1,AD2-X2,AE1-X2).

Comment: Can you provide more information? is this happening over multiple cells? what is the intent?  Please read the following: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information about this case.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? The formula is slowing down your already slow worksheet and you want to be able to press a button to fill a column with data according to the formula. There is a drawback that this column will only update when you press the button. BTW, Which column is it?

Comment: I see you have asked the same question again. There is no need for that. You can edit this question anytime. There is an **edit** button right below your post. Click it and make changes.

Comment: I used tu run macro with excel formula =IF(J2<>J1,AD2-X2,AE1-X2). But it's very slow calculation, i think its because running a formula. So i try to simplify the formula to vba code. My column is AE2 =IF(J2<>J1,AD2-X2,AE1-X2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to your question.  However, it is limited to only work with OP information.  Also, if the calculations are taking too long then, you should try setting your calculation to Manual (Formulas->Calculation Options->Manual).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunIF()
    Dim vntOut As Variant
    Dim rngSame As Range

    With ActiveSheet

        Set rngSave = .Range("X2")

        If (LCase(Trim(.Range("J2").Value)) <> LCase(Trim(.Range("J1").Value))) Then
            vntOut = .Range("AD2").Value - rngSave.Value
        Else
            vntOut = .Range("AE1").Value - rngSave.Value
        End If

        .Range("AE2").value = vntOut

        Set rngSave = Nothing
    End With

End Sub
```

And here is your code converted to use Column J:

```
Private Sub CommandButton12_Click()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i as long 

    With Sheets("Shipping Schedule")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 to LastRow

            set r = .Range("J" & I)
        'For Each r In .Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
            If LCase(Trim(r.Value)) <> LCase(Trim(r.Offset(-1, 0).Value)) Then
                'ae2 =                      "AD2"             -   "x2"
                r.Offset(0, 21).Value = r.Offset(0, 20).Value - r.Offset(0, 14).Value
            Else
                'ae2 =                      "AE1"         -        "x2"
                r.Offset(0, 21).Value = r.Offset(-1, 21).Value - r.Offset(0, 14).Value
            End If

            set r = nothing 

        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

However, you should increment with I instead of for each as the cells are dependent on the previous row and excel may not loop through the range like you would prefer.

Comment: What's up? the comments are not for discussion. you should start a chat for that.

Comment: Hi can i have a discussion with you by email regarding my matter?

Comment: Hello, it almost work but, i tried to use else function and fail. How about else for function "AE1-X2"? It almost done

Comment: OK, I updated it to work with AE1 and X1 as well as AD2 and X2.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton12_Click()

    Dim x As Long

    Dim LastRow As Long 

    Sheets("Shipping Schedule").Select


    With Sheets("Shipping Schedule")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each r In .Range("N2:N" & LastRow)

            If r.Value <> "" Then

                r.Offset(0, 19).Value = ………………………………….              

            End if      

        Next r      

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: r.Offset(0, 19).Value = …………………………………. (Convert this formula to vba excel code =IF(J2<>J1,AD2-X2,AE1-X2)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel Formula to VBA: Fill Column

```
Sub FillColumn()

    Const cCol As Variant = "J"    ' Last-Row-Column Letter/Number
    Const cCol1 As Variant = "AD"
    Const cCol2 As Variant = "X"
    Const cCol3 As Variant = "AE"
    Const cFirstR As Long = 1      ' First Row

    Dim rng As Range    ' Last Used Cell in Last-Row-Column
    Dim i As Long       ' Row Counter

    Set rng = Columns(cCol).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For i = cFirstR To rng.Row - 1
        If Cells(i + 1, cCol) <> Cells(i, cCol) Then
            Cells(i + 1, cCol3) = Cells(i + 1, cCol1) - Cells(i + 1, cCol2)
          Else
            Cells(i + 1, cCol3) = Cells(i, cCol3) - Cells(i + 1, cCol2)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```